# How can I compare the first N elements of a std::set?

Tags: c++, iterator, set

How can I compare first "n" elements of two sets are equal or not? My following program doesn't work, why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <set>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  int n = 2;
  int myints1[] = {75,23,65,42,13};
  int myints2[] = {70,23,65,42,13};
  set<int> myset1 (myints1,myints1+5);
  set<int> myset2 (myints2,myints2+5);

  if(std::equal(myset1.begin(),myset1.begin() + n ,myset2.begin()))    //error
  std::copy(std::myset1.begin(),myset1.begin() + n,ostream_iterator<int>(cout," ")); //error
  cout << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

> UPDATE:

Is there a way to compare a specific element as well ?
Thanks.

Comment: Since `set::set` iterators aren't random access you are limited to starting from one end of the container and stepping element-by-element. The `std::advance` algorithm allows you to jump to an offset from an iterator but it just performs the O(n) loop when given a bidirectional iterator.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

std::set iterators are bidirectional, not random-access. You can't say `begin() + n` with them. Instead you might want to use `std::advance`.

```
std::set<int>::iterator it(myset1.begin());
std::advance(it,n);
if(std::equal(myset1.begin(),it,myset2.begin()))
  std::copy(myset1.begin(),it,ostream_iterator<int>(cout," "));
```

Comment: +1 Interesting, but is the order guaranteed to stay the same for a given implementation?

Comment: std::set contents are always ordered by the key values in the container. The default ordering is `less<key>` so the first n elements will be the n "smallest".

Comment: @Blastfurnace: Aha, then the "first n" elements does make sense (it's just highly confusing in the mathematical sense)

Comment: @Blastfurnace: Is there a way to compare a specific element as well ? Like in my code I want to compare the last element alone. How can I do that? Any ideas ? Thanks.

Comment: @Sunil: The set container supports reverse iterators so the simplest way to address the last element is via `myset1.rbegin()`. Note the `r` in the member function name. If you want to address an arbitrary element you are stuck with `std::advance`.

Comment: @Blastfurnace: got it but cant we use something like `(*it1 == *it2)` to compare arbitrary element?

Comment: Sure, Sunil, you can compare whatever values you want. If you want to compare the last elements of the two sets, just do this: `*s1.rbegin() == *s2.rbegin()`.

Comment: @Rob: `(*myset1.rbegin() > *myset2.rbegin())` works but `(*myset1.end() > *myset2.end())` doesn't work. I don't understand why ?

Comment: @Sunil: You can always compare elements once you have iterators to them. I thought you were asking how to quickly compare something like the 5th elements or the 20th elements. Obtaining an iterator to an arbitrary offset is a linear operation.

Comment: @Blastfurnace: I was asking that too. I figured out to compare elements once I've iterators to them but isn't `myset1.end()` same as `myset1.rbegin()` ?

Comment: @Sunil: Remember that `end()` is an iterator to one-past-the-last element. You never want to dereference `end()`.

Comment: @Sunil: No, `rbegin()` is the beginning of a reversed view of the container. If you iterate from `rbegin()` to `rend()` you get the container contents in reverse order. Just as you can't dereference `end()` you shouldn't dereference `rend()`. These just exists as sentinels.

Comment: @Blastfurnace: Oh okay. Now I get it. Thanks a lot. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @Sunil: Glad I could help. Reverse iterators are handy when you need them but it can be counter-intuitive that doing `++it` on a reverse iterator is actually moving backwards.